# multiple canvas layers memory leak

Tags: javascript, memory, canvas, layer

I am trying to add multiple canvas layers into the DOM and am finding that while adding many layers is not an issue if I use .fillText to add content to the layers I suddenly get a lot of memory being used, often to the point that firefox crashes and brings down the entire machine. If anyone out there can see that I am doing something inthe wrong way I would appreciate any advice you might give - thanks tb!

Code below - this is a simplified version of the real thing but demonstrates the issue - if I increase the number of times the loops run I very quickly encounter problems. If I comment out the .fillText code however, I seem to be able to add many layers but as soon as I try and .fillText them my memory use goes through the roof....

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>.</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="canvasCont"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    $(function () {
    var id = 1;
    var top = 100;

    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        var left = 100;

        for ( a = 0; a < 5; a++ ) {

            $('#canvasCont').append(
                "<canvas width='1300px' height='1300px' style='position: absolute; border: 1px solid black;' id='canvas_" + id + "'>" +
                    "Your browser does not support canvas" +
                "</canvas>"
            );

            var context = document.getElementById( 'canvas_' + id ).getContext( '2d' );

            context.font = "10px Verdana";
            context.fillStyle = "red";
            context.fillText(
                id,
                left,
                top
            );

            left += 55;
            id++;
        }

        top = top + 55;
    }

}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FillText uses A LOT of memory to display, since it's vector-based drawing.
(I would suggest using images, if you intend on displaying always the same text)

I'll also add that you're creating mutliple canvases with quite high resolution, which can be tough for your machine.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The reason I'm using .fillText is that I am displaying dynamic values - I intend to have an interval running which will retrieve new values from the server via AJAX and then clear the particular canvas layer associated with that value and then apply .fillText again with the updated value. Thanks anyway though!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found [this library.....paperJS](http://paperjs.org/) which solved the performance issues with multiple live data points on multiple canvas layers. Highly recommended.